# Why is information about triage and help and improvement review queues there in help center?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, review-queue, help-center

In [this help center article](https://askubuntu.com/help/reviews-intro), there is some information about *triage* and *help and improvement review queues*.

> - [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – Stack Overflow only - 500 reputation. The primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort questions into groups: good as is, needs community editing, or should be closed/flagged.
> - [Help and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-help-and-improvement) - Stack Overflow only - 2,000 reputation. This queue lets you edit questions that were flagged in Triage as needing community editing.

Since the aforementioned review queues are specific to Stack Overflow, I don't understand why the above quoted information exists in [Ask Ubuntu help center](https://askubuntu.com/help).

Why does this information exist in Ask Ubuntu help center? Shouldn't it be removed?

Comment: I guess SE just  copy / paste the help center across all sites, for consistency probably, so I don't think the mods here could change it if they wanted.

Comment: @MarkKirby May be the mods can notify SE staff by adding [meta-tag:status-review] tag.

Comment: Because mods can't edit the page.  There's no way to make it specific, that's a network-wide static page.

Comment: @ThomasWard I do know know that mods can't edit it. But SE staff can. I guess adding a [meta-tag:status-review] tag will bring this post under SE staff's attention.

Comment: I am just going to leave this here, so if anyone is following this question, they can see it on meta too https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366993/why-is-information-about-triage-and-help-and-improvement-review-queues-there-in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [answer Tinkeringbell wrote on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367009/284336) is pretty much the explanation for this but I'll throw a bit of additional information out there.

As mentioned in [Workflow changes for review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363552/workflow-changes-for-review-queues) - Help & Improvement will be retired in the near future - so that's one of them removed. Triage will not be retired but it may be added to additional sites that wish to have it, so it will be applicable in more places (though we'll likely have to change "Stack Overflow only" to "where applicable").

These pages can't be specialized for each site without making them have to be custom edited on every site. This is why moderators can't edit these pages - we need to have them be identical so that they can be updated. They work just like regular posts but we do have some ability to reference tables to pull in information - that's how the reputation levels for different privileges are custom to the site.

As to changing the order so that the Triage option is at the bottom - it's *possible* but the items are (generally) in order based on when someone unlocks the queue - though this doesn't work on beta sites or MSE where the rep levels are different because (again) we can't adjust the content that appears on that level on a per-site basis.

Comment: Update: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1252795

Answer (score 1):

I think it's quite nice that it's there - it's like we're overhearing something not exactly meant for us but that may nonetheless be of interest. Like, if our site became immensely busier for some reason, we might think about requesting the addition of those queues. Or, we might see this stuff in the Help Center and feel a surge of generous interest in helping the poor overworked Stack Overflow reviewers.

Comment: If I am not wrong, help center articles are meant to be precise and not lengthy.

Comment: Sure, but it's just a few extra lines

Comment: Hmm. As you feel that it's just few extra lines, I have an alternate suggestion. Why not place the SO review queues at the end and give more preference to the site's review queues? I know the reviews queues are ordered according to reputation, but we can bend the rules (lol).

Comment: @RandomPerson that seems like it would be an improvement

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please be more clear?

Comment: @RandomPerson I mean, I think your idea of putting the SO - only queues at the end is a good idea

Comment: Update: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1252795